# Only first Mysqli Insert query with PHP working while others fail

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have been converting a web application of mine which creates quizzes with multiple answers from working with a PostgreSQL DB to a MySQL DB. The queries below which worked fine previously in PostgreSQL aren't working in MySQL.

The first query does get inserted correctly, however the second and third do not get inserted at all.

The strange thing however is that a serial ID is generated for the two failed queries. I can tell because when I retry the inserting, the first query which succeeds goes up by 3 ID numbers each time. I have also used echo before each query to check that all the variables are correct which they are. Another thing that confuses me is I am also inserting a record into another table which also works fine, it seems to be inserting multiple times into the same table that is not working?

Help to overcome this difficulty would be greatly appreciated!

```
//answer 1
$answercreatequery = mysqli_query($db_handle, "INSERT INTO answer (answerid, questionid, adescription, afilelocation, iscorrect) VALUES( default, '".$thisquestionid."', '".$adescription1."', '".$afilelocation."', '".$iscorrect1."') ");


//answer 2                  
$answercreatequery = mysqli_query($db_handle, "INSERT INTO answer (answerid, questionid, adescription, afilelocation, iscorrect) VALUES( default, '".$thisquestionid."', '".$adescription2."', '".$afilelocation."', '".$iscorrect2."') ");


//answer 3
$answercreatequery = mysqli_query($db_handle, "INSERT INTO answer (answerid, questionid, adescription, afilelocation, iscorrect) VALUES( default, '".$thisquestionid."', '".$adescription3."', '".$afilelocation."', '".$iscorrect3."') ");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to pass "default" for ids in mysql. mysql handles that automatically. just omit the id column and value from your statements.

also, you're wide open for sql injections.

see here about prepared statements:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: Alternatively pass it as a `NULL`

Comment: @ydaetskcoR hmm, i didn't know that either. 7 am and i've already learned something.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Also I'm using mysqli_real_escape_string on all data entered by users, would I still be open without using prepared statements?

Comment: @mark that depends on who you ask and the competency/time of the hacker. against simple bots and scanners you'll be fine, but eventually you'll encounter a hacker who knows how to bypass it with carefully encoded input